# d3.scale.category20() gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'category20' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to embed D3 bar charts into my site, shown here:
[image: d3 sample bar chart]

From this recipe: http://bl.ocks.org/erikvullings/51cc5332439939f1f292 But the dynamic cherrypy sever gives me an error.

If I take the HTML from that page and host it on my static server, it works fine. Example: http://feedbackcommons.org/s/test.html

The javascript error is this exact line:

```
<script>
// Color scale
var color = d3.scale.category20();
</script>
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'category20' of undefined
```

I tried stripping out all of the other D3 recipe JS code and only including that one line shown above. Still, I get an error. So something else on the page is interfering. But I can't recreate the error by cutting and pasting that code into a simple HTML file and loading on another static server.

I would guess that something in the header JS is an issue, but if I include that in the test page on the static server, it loads fine.

**I'm using https://d3js.org Version 4.9.1.**

Here is the full header HTML/JS stuff:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="js"><head>
<link rel="profile" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://love.feedbackcommons.org/static/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://love.feedbackcommons.org">
<title>Explore Your Survey</title>
<script src="/static/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="/static/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script> -->
<script src="/static/js/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/d3-scale-chromatic.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/d3pie.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/widget-filter-formatter-jui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/widget-math.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/word_wrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/theme.bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/filter.formatter.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/theme.jui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.css">
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/s/bootstrap-tokenfield/dist/bootstrap-tokenfield.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<style>
  @import url("/static/css/system.base.css");
</style>
<style>
  @import url("/static/css/date.css");
  @import url("/static/css/datepicker.1.7.css");
  @import url("/static/css/field.css");
  @import url("/static/css/node.css");
  @import url("/static/css/views.css");
  @import url("/static/css/admin_menu.css");
  @import url("/static/css/admin_menu.uid1.css");
</style>
<style>
  @import url("/static/css/ctools.css");
</style>
<style>
    @import url("/static/css/style.css");
</style>
<!-- HTML5 element support for IE6-8 -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.2.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="/static/js/drupal/jquery.min.js?v=1.8.3"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/drupal.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/admin_devel.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/admin_menu.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/devel_krumo_path.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/affix.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/alert.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/button.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/carousel.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/collapse.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/modal.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/popover.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/tab.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/drupal/transition.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
    else
      e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

So what are some reasons why I would get a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'category20' of undefined
```

for `d3.scale.category20()` (d3.scale is Undefined) if this same D3 version works outside of my server?

Comment: `d3.scale.category20()` was a part of d3 v3. As you're using d3 v4, I'd suggest you go through [d3/CHANGES docs](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#scales-d3-scale) to learn the map (new methods) and if you're looking for different colorScales specifically, [d3-scale-chromatic](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic#categorical) is what you'd want to be looking at (included in the bundle of d3 v5). A quick fix would be to switch to d3 v3.

Comment: Im pretty sure d3 v4 changed how one uses the `scale` methods.

Comment: thanks. I foudn that although I explicitly call d3 v3 in the header, it was somehow loading `d3 v4.9.1` from some buried file elsewhere. Even removing v3 from the header allows D3 to work, so I updated my code to v4 and it works.

Comment: The deleted answer is correct: there is a version expectation mismatch: either the author of the OP, or a d3 lib the author is using, is expecting d3 version 3, but the code is trying to use a d3 object from version 4 or higher. I updated the answer to make that more clear and voted to undelete.